# Why am I getting a name error when I defined the variable?

Tags: python, list

```
def calculate_letter_grades(test_score):
        if test_score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif test_score >= 80 and test_score < 90:
            return "B"
        elif test_score >= 70 and test_score < 80:
            return "C"
        elif test_score >= 60 and test_score < 70:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"
def caluculate_avg(scores):
    all_grades = 0
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        all_grades = all_grades + scores[i]
    return all_grades / float(len(scores))

for c in range(6):
    scores = []
    student_name =  input("Please enter the student\'s name: ")
    for x in range(6):
        test_score = int(input("Please enter test scores: "))
        scores.append(test_score)
    scores_averaged = calculate_avg(scores)
    print("Student: ", students_name)
    for z in range(len(scores)):
        print("Test Score: ", scores[z], "Test Letter Grade: ", calcualte_letter_grades(scores[z]))
    print("Average test score: ", scores_averaged)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
"NameError: name 'calculate_avg' is not defined"
```

I don't understand why though, I thought I had it defined.

Comment: Re-read this closely: `def caluculate_avg(scores):`. And this too: `calcualte_letter_grades(scores[z])`

Comment: Thank you, I need to change my IDE

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss spelled the word "calculate" on

`def caluculate_avg(scores):`

change to

`def calculate_avg(scores):`

Answer (score 0):

The function name is spelled incorrectly 'caluculate'.

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is `caluculate_avg` but you call `calculate_avg` 
So that is just a typo problem and change this line

```
def caluculate_avg(scores):
```

To this

```
def calculate_avg(scores):
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a typo in function name and calling.
You are defining

```
def caluculate_avg(scores):
```

but you are using

```
scores_averaged = calculate_avg(scores)
```

Change the function definition to

```
 def calculate_avg(scores):
```

Answer (score 0):

You called your function with a different name, **'calculate_avg'** instead of **'caluculate_avg',** make sure you have the same function name when calling it